# php mysql if exists update else insert

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a PHP code that will take the IP, time and the times that the same IP has been in the page. For now I have done this:

```
require "connect.php" ;

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function ip_add($ip){

$query = "INSERT INTO hits_ip VALUES ('' ,'', '$ip' , now()) ";

@$query_run = mysql_query($query);

}

ip_add($user_ip);
```

But count isn't working. I have tried a lot of options but haven't found an option to check if a `$user_ip` for example line is exist and if yes to chance the count every time they refresh.

Comment: So you need to count the number of visits from that IP?

Answer (score 1):

Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement to get this right.

That said, in general you should be able to perform `INSERT` ... `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), like:

```
INSERT INTO hits_ip VALUES ('' ,'', '$ip' , now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hitcount=hitcount+1;
```

This will insert a row into your table or increments `hitcount` column if the row already exists. For this to work you must have unique index for that table (e.g. have defined `ip` as primary key).

Your second option is to keep your current query and just insert a row for *each* hit. You can then combine all those rows for statistical purposes as you deem fit, e.g:

```
SELECT ip, count(*) 
 FROM hits_ip 
 WHERE hitdate between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
 GROUP BY ip;
```

Further down the rabbit hole you go, more bizarre options appear, like [creating a trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on `hits_ip` table to update a second statistics table. The thing is that you alone know what fits your use case.

Comment: Sorry that i'm asking but how do i get my CREATE TABLE statement?                                                 when i im typing the first code u gave me and refreshing the webpage it wont insert the info at all to the db , this is the Structure tab the                      https://i.gyazo.com/1630cbd28d26f2de4bcf0990a8483197.png                                Thanks.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `hits_ip` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;

Comment: @Tommerzil, I'm not sure I follow you logic. `id` is auto_increment primary key while `ip` isn't even unique, yet you always insert blank `id` which ensures that new row will be created. Which row do you expect to be updated in case of duplicates?